# How to apply gradient color to Flutter Icon on the web?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, icons, gradient

I know `ShaderMask` is not supported on web, but I would need a way to apply gradients to icons on web. I spent a good few hours trying to find a workaround but couldn't. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I have moved to dev channel and `ShaderMask` work fine for me.

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't work in stable. And I can only work with stable versions.